# Python Selenium : I want to click a button. Code runs well but button is not yet clicked

Tags: python, selenium, button, iframe

Code executes properly, but button it is not getting clicked so as to generates a new set of field for further data entry.

```
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=options)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("tmscontent"))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'btnaddrow')))
element.click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()`
```

HTML code

```
`<input type="button" name="btnaddrow" id="btnaddrow" value=" Add Row " class="butts" onclick="addrow(document.getElementById('baserow'))">`
```

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Have you tried addressing the element by some other attribute, xpath for example?

Comment: Try xpath. Sample code here https://github.com/arun-n-a/github-linkedin-tutorial. 
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/arun-saanthi_python3-selenium-automations-activity-6656001728028176384-YumL

Comment: Why do you have `driver.switch_to.default_content()` ? Are you in any iframe ? if so, how did you switch to that ?

Comment: Yes it is within an iframe

Comment: any difference if you say wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'btnaddrow'))).click()?